# Spark streaming print on received stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stream, spark-streaming

What I am trying ot achieve is basically print `"hello world"` each time I receive a stream of data.

I know that on each stream I can call the function `foreachRDD` but that does not help me because:

1. It might be that there is no data processed
2. I don't want to print hello on each rdd, I want to print hello on the entire stream (whether I received data or not).

Basicaly, each time the program tries to fetch data (and it does so every 30 seconds lets say because of the spark streaming context) I would like to print hello.

Is there a way of doing this? is there like a onlisten event for spark streaming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each batch interval (in your case, 30 seconds) the `DStream` will contain one and only one `RDD`, which internally is divided by several partitions. You can check if it's not empty and only then print hello world:

```
// Create DStream from source
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty) println("hello world") }
```

Comment: Four basic time parameters are window, slide, batch and checkpoint interval. Batches constitutes window, steps in time by batches are sliding, and for persistance a suitable checkpoint interval must be chosen.